# Native AR in Xamarin mobile application

Tags: mobile, xamarin, augmented-reality

I've been looking on the internet if there is any way to develop an application that uses AR natively on Xamarin Mobile (iOS and Android) .

I found a video of a presentation by Frank A. Krueger in the event Xamarin Evolve 2014 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLFn7Y_y_HI) and its demo code on Github (https://github.com/praeclarum/ardemo) .

Apparently Frank managed to develop AR natively on Xamarin . So I wonder if this is possible or is only possible using another tool , such as:

- Vuforia Wikitude ARToolkit Etc

Comment: So it is possible? Yes, you answered your own question.... Sure you can use an 3rd-party toolkit to short-cut development time depending upon time, cost and the toolkit abilities vs. your coding abilities and app requirements or you can code it from scratch using the various features that each platform surfaces...

Comment: Maybe I didnt do the right question. I'm looking for some tutorial or some basic steps about AR with xamarin.

Comment: Well, Frank's Evolve talk and demo code is a great start. He talk concerning the "math" is crucial in understanding the AR basics and his code is in C#...  I would also look at MS' HoloLens emulator and SDK, while not mobile-oriented, the concepts all apply. Also I would look at the third-party AR sdks, while most are not C# and none(?) are Xamarin-based, the concepts all apply. In the end, AR is all about a live world background and 2d/3d elements placed on top... so in terms of 2d/3d, start looking at OpenGL, game engines, etc.. lots a C#/mobile tutorials in that area...